# python - checking string for certain words

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is that, if I ask a question only answerable by Yes and 
No, I want to make sure that yes or no is the answer. Otherwise, it will stop.

```
 print("Looks like it's your first time playing this game.")
 time.sleep(1.500)
 print("Would you like to install the data?")
 answer = input(">").lower
 if len(answer) > 1:

    if answer == "no":
        print("I see. You want to play portably. We will be using a password system.")
        time.sleep(1.500)
        print("Your progress will be encrypted into a long string. Make sure to remember it!")
    else:
        print("Didn't understand you.")

elif len(answer) > 2:

    if word == "yes":
        print("I see. Your progress will be saved. You can back it up when you need to.")
        time.sleep(1.500)

else:
    print("Didn't understand you.")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
answer = input(">").lower
```

should be

```
answer = input(">").lower()
```

Second, `len(answer) > 1` is true for both `"no"` and `"yes"` (and anything larger than one character, for that matter). The `elif` block will never be evaluated. Without modifying significantly the logic of your current code, you should do instead:

```
if answer == 'no':
    # do this
elif answer == 'yes':
    # do that
else:
    print("Didn't understand you.")
```

Comment: In five minutes (because I suck), I'll be marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
if word.lower() in ('yes', 'no'):
```

would be the simplest approach (assuming case doesn't matter).

Side-note:

```
answer = input(">").lower
```

Is assigning a reference to the `lower` method to `answer`, not calling it. You need to add parens, `answer = input(">").lower()`. Also, if this is Python 2, you need to use `raw_input`, not `input` (In Python 3, `input` is correct).